# Writing to Windows Event log using the existing source "Backup"

Tags: event-log

I would like to write to the Windows event log using the existing source "Windows Backup", but I get this error-text in the event:

> The description for Event ID 8 from source Microsoft-Windows-Backup cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> Hello World

Writing to Event log using .NET class `System.Diagnostics.EventLog` and poweshell.

I've tried different Event ID's (0,1,4,5,9,1000,1001).
Does it take more than the right ID to successfully write an event without getting this error-text?

Same goes for the source "Microsoft-Windows-Backup" and "Application", the later might not have any ID descriptions, but I assume the two other have.

I'm aware I can register my own source but it require elevated permission which is an issue in my use-case.